# Checking for alignment on an axis

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Suppose I have an array of 5 objects, each time the touches the screen I generate a new array and save the previous objects in another array.

Is there a way to check if the object align perfectly on only axis with a reasonable error margin and detect objects wrongfully aligned?

I could do it using mathematics but I want to see if I could take advantage of `overlaps` in Libgdx or a similar method.

Comment: Reaching out here because you deleted your other question before I could reply. No, you completely misunderstood what I was saying. Overlapping rectangles without collision is not impossible. It's in fact very common.

Comment: @DMGregory ahh thanks a lot, I'll edit and undelete my question tomorrow and give a demo if possible and notify you, it's getting late today. thanks for eveything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check if actors are aligned with the overlap method. (I assume your objects are actors, or anything with x and y positions as attributes)

To check if some actors are aligned on the same axis you just have to check if their x position (or y if you want to compare by y) are the same

```
private boolean objectsAligned(Array<Actors> actors)
{
    // Get the base X value you want to align on, here i take the first actor's x position
    float x = actors.get(0).getX();

    for (Actor actor : actors)
    {
        if (actor.getX() != x)
            return false;
    }

    // If the condition above is never true, everything is aligned
    return true;
}
```

Now, if you want to add a margin to this alignement. You need to compute your min X and max X values with the error margin as a range and check if every actor's X is in this range.

Comment: I didn't use Actor, I used <Rectangle> but no big deal I'll modify my code and try it

Comment: Rectangle also got position, in fact this code will work with every class that has position.